# method for concatenating two different type arrays

Tags: java, arrays, join, concatenation

1. this is my code, has no error while compile, but have run time error.
2. have exception ans do not show me output, where did i go wrong?

   ```
   public static Object [] concatenate(int[]a ,double[] b) {
       int l=a.length;
       int  L = b.length;
       Object[]  ob=new Object[l+ L];
       for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
           ob[i] = a[i];
       }
   ```
3. i created the new object to add the two arrays into it.

   ```
       for(int j=0;j<L;j++){
           ob[j+l] = b[j];
       }
   ```
4. And used two for for printing them.

   ```
       System. out. print (ob);
       return ob;
   }
   ```

Comment: If you want people to read your code, **indent it**!!!

Comment: the problem was in the way i printed it. i used Arrays.toString() and it just worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you do this

```
System. out. print (ob);
```

you are actually printing the  hash code of the Array object, and not its content..
something like this can make more sense:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ob));
```

---

So I tried your code and works fine

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] intArr = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < intArr.length; i++) {
        intArr[i] = 0;
    }
    double[] doubleArr = new double[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < doubleArr.length; i++) {
        doubleArr[i] = 1.11;
    }
    int l = intArr.length;
    int L = doubleArr.length;
    Object[] ob = new Object[l + L];
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        ob[i] = intArr[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < L; i++) {
        ob[l + i] = doubleArr[i];
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ob));
}
```

this prints

> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11, 1.11]